# Constant-Time comparison

Tags: .net, algorithm, cryptography

A relatively simple question:

It *appears* that C# doesn't come with baked-in constant-time comparison methods or extensions, why not? Sure it's a simple algorithm, but it seems so basic it should be included.

It is typically not recommend to write any of your own crypto code, however it appears that there aren't any libraries for this kind of purpose, am I missing some?

See algorithms like this: http://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/

Comment: For small values, you can XOR the 2 values against one another and check if the output of the XOR is 0.  For larger values or just more flexibility, hash the input value and XOR it against the hash of the expected value and check for 0.  This is simple, and it is constant-time.  I don't know why it's not part of the standard libraries.  I agree it should be.  CryptoSecureEquals or something like that.

Comment: Asking why the .Net standard library was designed in some way is off topic, because this is highly opinionated. Can you edit your question to make it on-topic and answerable so that @WDS may post a proper answer?

Comment: @WDS For long values you can simply binary-or together the xor of the individual bytes. That's what I do in my crypto library.

Comment: @ArtjomB: "Should I just extend them as needed or am I missing a third party library that provides stuff like this?", it's right there, very answerable. The question about the standard libs provides context.

Comment: @StrangeWill Asking whether you should implement it yourself or use some third part library is opinion-based and should be closed. Asking for a third party library is a recommendation request for an off-site resource and should be closed. Asking whether you missed the requested functionality in the *standard library* (it's not what you're asking here) is an answerable question, but it is not a good question, because yes/no-questions generally don't lead to good answers.

Comment: @ArtjomB. " am I missing a third party library?" I'm pretty much explicitly asking "is there a third party library, or am I expected to just roll my own?" It isn't down to opinion at all the way that it is phrased. For anyone interested in writing crypto-safe code in .NET this is a pretty good point considering the golden standard on that subject is "don't write your own".

Comment: From dotnet core 2.1 there is [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicOperations.FixedTimeEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptographicoperations.fixedtimeequals).